# How can I print an array easily?

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working with arrays, and everytime I need to print one I do a for loop.

```
System.out.print("[");
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
}
System.out.println("]");
```

This seems like a feature that would be built into java (I am using java). Is there a built in way to print arrays?

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));` should produce identical output there.

Comment: (Remember that it is possible always write a single function and use it later .. not that it is [necessarily] warranted here, but "every time" is too much typing. Also, separate the operations to reduce coupling: turning the array into a string representation and outputting said string.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use: 
`Arrays.toString(arr)`
for normal arrays and/or 
`Arrays.deepToString(arr)` 
for arrays within arrays. 
Both these methods return the string representation of the array.

See the [Arrays docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for more.

Answer (score 9):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also write your own method that does the same thing as `Arrays.toString()`:

```
/** Converts an array into a CSV string. */

public static <T> String arrayToCsv(T[] someArray) {

    if (someArray == null || someArray.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

    for (T thisT : someArray) {
        String val = (thisT == null) ? "null" : thisT.toString();
        csv.append(val).append(", ");
    }

    return csv.toString();
}
```

Test it:

```
Double[] doubleArray = { 2.4, 3.6, 6.5 };
String[] stringArray = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };

System.out.println(arrayToCsv(doubleArray));
System.out.println(arrayToCsv(stringArray));
```